Xero API - PUT Gift Card payments in minus
When trying to PUT Gift Card purchase to increase the account's current liability in Xero, I get an error from Xero's response:

Payment amounts must be positive amounts

A gift card can be used as a payment redemption (decrease liability), and a customer can also purchase a gift card (increase liability). We need to be able to report it in minus as well.
I'm trying to do that with an authorised invoice status.
I have tried to export payment in minus on an "authorised" invoice status in Xero, expecting to be able to put payments in positive and negative.
I'm getting a validation error from Xero API:

payment amount must be positive


One suggestion is to use a current liability account in the invoice line item and then handle the gift card as described here. You could also consider prepayments.
However, it may be best to talk to an accountant that has Xero knowledge to ensure that you are compliant with the tax rules in the area your integration will be working.
